# Subclassing a Generic class

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to subclass a generic class in Swift but no matter what I do the compiler just keeps complaining, or worse, segfaulting.

This is the closest I got to compiling it, but then I am unable to create an instance of the subclass because the compiler is for some reason unable to infer what `T` is.

```
protocol GenericDataSourceCellProtocol {
    associatedtype ModelType
    var model: ModelType? {get set}
}

struct MyCellState {}

class MyCell: UITableViewCell, GenericDataSourceCellProtocol {
    var model: MyCellState?
}

class Generic2DDataSource<U, T>
where U:GenericDataSourceCellProtocol, U:UITableViewCell, T == U.ModelType {

    let items: [[T]]
    init (items: [[T]]) {
        self.items = items
    }
}


class SubclassedDataSource: Generic2DDataSource<MyCell, MyCellState> {}

let state = MyCellState()
let items = [[state]]
let datasource = SubclassedDataSource(items: items)
// cannot convert value of type '[Array<MyCellState>]' to expected argument type '[[T]]'
```

Is there a way to make this work? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of stuff going on here, very non-trivial Swift type system stuff. But, is this what you are going for?

```
protocol GenericDataSourceCellProtocol {
    associatedtype ModelType

    var model: ModelType? {get set}
}

struct MyCellState {}

class MyCell: UITableViewCell, GenericDataSourceCellProtocol {

    typealias ModelType = MyCellState

    var model: MyCellState?
}

class Generic2DDataSource<U> where U: GenericDataSourceCellProtocol, U: UITableViewCell {

    typealias T = U.ModelType

    let items: [[T]]

    init(items: [[T]]) {
        self.items = items
    }
}


class SubclassedDataSource: Generic2DDataSource<MyCell> {

}

let state = MyCellState()
let items = [[state]]
let datasource = SubclassedDataSource(items: items)
```

And, I think what you have should technically be valid because I found that if I change your code to this it will make the error go away:

```
protocol GenericDataSourceCellProtocol {
    associatedtype ModelType

    var model: ModelType? {get set}
}

struct MyCellState {}

class MyCell: UITableViewCell, GenericDataSourceCellProtocol {

    typealias ModelType = MyCellState

    var model: ModelType?
}

class Generic2DDataSource<U, T> where U: GenericDataSourceCellProtocol, U: UITableViewCell, T == U.ModelType {

    let items: [Array<U.ModelType>]

    init(items: [Array<U.ModelType>]) {
        self.items = items
    }

    func thing() -> T {
        let value = items[0][0]

        return value
    }
}

class SubclassedDataSource: Generic2DDataSource<MyCell, MyCellState> {
}
```

Notice I added a function `thing` to the base class. I did that because in Xcode you can option+click on the variable `value` and it'll let you know what type the compiler has determined it to be. In this case, `value` is type `T` even though I specified `items` to be `[Array<U.ModelType>]`. They should be the same because of the `T == U.ModelType` but for some reason it can't figure that out during the subclassing compilation.

Based on what you had, though, I think `T` isn't really necessary since you're forming a relationship between U and T. Simply providing U as a generic parameter should be sufficient, as in my first code block.

Comment: Hey Allen that's a great answer and it definitely solves the problem, thanks! I'm curious to see if anyone else can come up with an explanation for the compiler behaviour in my original example so I'll wait a couple of days before marking your answer as accepted. Thanks again, I appreciate you taking the time to look into it!

Comment: I'm interested, too.

Comment: @Rog For kicks I put your code in Xcode 9b6 and it compiled and ran perfectly, so it seems like it was a compiler bug that has been fixed.